# Commutativity of monoid object on $\mathcal{D}$-spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, monoidal-categories, stable-homotopy-theory

Let ($\mathcal{D}, \otimes, 0)$ be a symmetric monoidal category enriched over pointed spaces, and denote by $\mathsf{Top}_*^\mathcal{D}$ to the category of "$\mathcal{D}$-spaces", the category of enriched functors.

There is a closed symmetric monoidal structure on $\mathcal{D}$-spaces given by Day convolution (a left Kan extension): if $D \in \mathcal{D}$ and $X,Y$ are $\mathcal{D}$-spaces, then $$(X \wedge Y)_D := \int^{A, B \in \mathcal{D}} \mathrm{Hom}_\mathcal{D} (A \otimes B, D) \wedge X_D \wedge Y_B.$$

Let $R$ be a commutative monoid object on $\mathcal{D}$-spaces, so there is a commutative diagram saying that the multiplication map $R \wedge R \to R$ and $$R \wedge R \overset{\cong}{\to} R \wedge R \to R$$ (symmetry isomorphism and then multiplication) coincide.

> **Question.** Is $R$  commutative if and only if the  diagram
>
> $$\require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}
> R_D \wedge R_{D'}
>  @>>> R_{D \otimes D'}\\
> @VVV @VVV \\
> R_{D'} \wedge R_D @>>> R_{D' \otimes D}
> \end{CD}$$
>
> commutes? According to [Schwede](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/schwede/equivariant.pdf), it should be the case, but I have not been able to give a proof of this, linking this explicit description with the symmetry isomorphism of the commutative monoid object.